# Can I do maven jetty restart on change of spring xmls?

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, maven-jetty-plugin

I am using IntelliJ IDEA to code a Java web project. The maven pom.xml looks like this

```
<build>
    <finalName>ucpportal-${project.version}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.21</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                </webApp>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

With some tweak in the run configuration when I am runing 'mvn jetty:run', it is reloading the new classes on every make.
My question is can I make any arrangement such that when I change the spring xml as well, it will restart the server to reflect the changes instead of doing it manually?

Comment: Try `<scanTargets><scanTarget>path/to/file</scanTarget></scanTargets>` in the `<configuration>`. It should pick file/dirs that aren't originally listened for, as mentioned [here](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#jetty-run-goal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @peeskillet. When I added the follwoing, it started working.

```
<scanTargetPatterns>
    <scanTargetPattern>
        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.xml</include>
        </includes>
    </scanTargetPattern>
</scanTargetPatterns>
```

I had to switch the window to make it working.